# Get type stored in binary field signature

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, clr, cil

Suppose you have a binary representation of a field signature in a .NET module, like `0604`. The 6 (`FIELD`) represents the field calling convention and the 4 (`ELEMENT_TYPE_I1`) represents the `I1` primitive type (see [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) for more on CIL). The signature can be from a debugger or assembly inspector, that is not important. What's more important, is it possible (using methods provided by .NET) to "parse" this signature and get the corresponding .NET type that the signature is representing?

Examples:

`0601` ⇒ `System.Void`
`0604` ⇒ `System.SByte`
`060E` ⇒ `System.String`
`061408020000` ⇒ `System.Int32[,]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some internal .NET methods that can do that:

```
public static unsafe Type GetTypeFromFieldSignature(byte[] signature, Type declaringType = null)
{
    declaringType = declaringType ?? typeof(object);
    Type sigtype = typeof(Type).Module.GetType("System.Signature");
    Type rtype = typeof(Type).Module.GetType("System.RuntimeType");
    var ctor = sigtype.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[]{typeof(void*), typeof(int), rtype}, null);
    fixed(byte* ptr = signature)
    {
        object sigobj = ctor.Invoke(new object[]{(IntPtr)ptr, signature.Length, declaringType});
        return (Type)sigtype.InvokeMember("FieldType", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, sigobj, null);
    }
}
```

This loads any valid field signature and returns the appropriate type.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about any public API that can do this, but [Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil) can parse this kind of signature internally, so you might be able to copy its code.

The relevant code is in [`SignatureReader.ReadTypeSignature()`](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/17d5b63fefde75d400e7fabb0a1e92755f8be5af/Mono.Cecil/AssemblyReader.cs#L2818).

Or maybe don't try to parse the assembly by yourself and use Cecil for that.